# Simplify code by making two for loops into one

Tags: c++

Right now I have two for loops and two if statements to run these for loops

```cpp
if(y > 0){
    for (int i = x - y; i < x + 1; i++) { 

    }
}

if(y < 0){
    for (int i = abs(x) + 1; i > x - 1; i--) {

    }
}
```

Is there any way to simplify this into one for loop? I have tried but I can't find a way to change direction of " < " sign.

Thanks for any help

Comment: More details are needed to understand what problem your code solves. It is hard to fix code, which you do not know what it suppose to do and when it is so short.

Comment: Are index,order important?

Comment: You can make one loop but it will likely be more complicated and less efficient than current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No trickery needed:

```
int start, end, inc;
if(y > 0){
    start = x-y;
    end = x+1;
    inc = 1;
} else {
    start = abs(x)+1;
    end = x-1;
    inc = -1;
}

for (int i = start; i != end; i += inc) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is a much simpler and cleaner solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is what you want, but only one loop at the end:

```
int start = 0;
std::function<bool(int)> cond = [](int){return false}; // Handle y == 0
int inc = 0;

if (y > 0) {
    start = x - y;
    cond = [&x](int i){ return i < x + 1;}
    inc = 1;
} else if (y < 0) {
    start = abs(x) + 1;
    cond = [&x](int i){ return i > x - 1; };
    inc = -1;
}

for (int i = start; cond(i); i += inc) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for being able to change the conditon.